# How to start and manage Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code works, fine, but i wonder .. conceptually, is it correct? Start the threads, wait for them to `join`. Should `ThreadPool` be used instead?

If possible, please comment

```
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();

for (Test test : testsToBeExecuted) {
  Thread t = new Thread(test);
  threads.add(t);
  t.start();
}

for (Thread thread : threads) {
  thread.join();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conceptually it looks fine.  You can use an ExecutorService which you create one like:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(testsToBeExecuted.size());
```

Thenyou would create a list of Callables and invokeAll on the executor service itself.  That in essence will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that ExecutorService is the way to go.  I have a utility class that uses ExecutorService to run a arbitrary number of tasks, collect the results and return them as a list.  ExecutorService will do all of the housekeeping for you.